# Emacs indent for C++ class method?

Tags: c++, emacs

For some reason, my emacs indent the c++ class method wrong.

Current:

```
class B
{
public:
    B()
        {
        }
};
```

But I want:

```
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
    }
};
```

Does anybody how to make it in .emacs?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems Emacs doesn't care much for your **pubic** constructor

Comment: typo, fixed. but the result is the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting `inline-open` to `'0`. That should place a brace that opens an in-class inline method on the same indent level. For example:

```
(c-set-offset 'inline-open '0)
```

There also might be something else, it is hard to say. [CC-Mode](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/cc-mode_32.html) document has more options and its description that might also be helpful to you.

Below is the example of my C++ style that is based on Linux coding style that might be of interest to you:

```
(defun vlad-cc-style()
  (c-set-style "linux")
  (c-set-offset 'innamespace '0)
  (c-set-offset 'inextern-lang '0)
  (c-set-offset 'inline-open '0)
  (c-set-offset 'label '*)
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '*)
  (c-set-offset 'access-label '/)
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
)

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'vlad-cc-style)
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!