# setting inline-open in modeline in emacs

Tags: emacs, modeline

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(c-set-offset 'inline-open 0)
```

Is there a way to "unset" inline-open in a modeline so that for some files inline-open does cause an indentation?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668744/emacs-indent-for-c-class-method) help with what you wanted to do? Looks like you can specify the setting per mode... or am I missing something?

Comment: That basically says what I am doing in my .emacs. I want to be able to override that setting on a per file basis by specifying a modeline. For tab widths, for e.g., I can override by this modeline : /* -\*- tab-width: 2 -\*- */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [file variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) like you suspect.  Either at the top, or at the bottom.

To do this at the top, add:

```
// -*- eval: (setq c-offsets-alist (assq-delete-all 'inline-open c-offsets-alist)) -*-
```

at the top of your file.

Alternatively, you can add it at the end of your file in a slightly different format.

```
// Local Variables:
// eval: (setq c-offsets-alist (assq-delete-all 'inline-open c-offsets-alist))
// End:
```

Note: Emacs will ask you the first time you open a file with this kind of trickery, and if you answer <kbd>!</kbd>, Emacs will automatically add this code to the list of things that are considered "safe" in file local variables.  It will set `safe-local-variable-values` in your `.emacs.customization.el` file.

Note 2: The snippets of code are using C++ style comments, adjust appropriately if you need C comments, or some other comment scheme.